# Complex filter factorizations

Tags: complex-numbers, convolution, signal-processing

There is a famous low pass filter $[1,2,1]$ in signal processing which can be factored in the sense of a convolution product over the real numbers : $[1,1] * [1,1]$. This is the only way to do it over the reals ( I think ). Today when I was bored, I investigated some complex valued filters and came to the conclusion that for $k = 3$ and $k = 5$ and $z_0 = e^{2\pi i/k}$, i.e. the "first" of the roots of unity for degree 3 and 5, I can build the same filter like:

$$[1,2,1] =  \left(z_0^{[m,l]} * z_0^{[-m,-l]}\right) \text{   where   } m-l = (0 \text{   mod   } k)$$
with the notation
$$z^{[a,b]} = [z^a,z^b]$$
What is cool is that there is a certain symmetry between these filters.

Now my question is two-fold :

1) Can we prove this will work in general for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$? ( I suspect it is true ).

2) Do there exist any techniques to factor other filters in any systematic fashion? Do we need to expand the complex numbers to do so or will they suffice?

---

**Edit** The answer is quite trivial as pointed out by MattL, but maybe can give raise to more interesting questions or something. [Here is a more interesting question (I hope).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558232/complex-filter-factorizations-continued)

Comment: Aren't you just computing $(c\cdot [1,1])*(\frac{1}{c}[1,1])$, with some generally complex number $c$, which will obviously give the same result as $[1,1]*[1,1]$?

Comment: Yep of course you're right. Sorry about that. I can change the question to be about modifying the factors to get other filters which I actually wanted to ask about, but forgot to write down. Hmm, not sure if it is OK to do that though. Maybe I should just make a new question.