# Complex filter factorizations with invariant points

Tags: abstract-algebra, factoring, convolution, signal-processing

Based on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558232/complex-filter-factorizations-continued), using the same $z_0$:
$$z_0 = e^{2\pi i / 8}$$
if we modify the sequence from previous question to look like this ($*$ denotes discrete convolution):
$$\left(z_0^{[-2k,3k]} * z_0^{[2k,-3k]}\right)$$
we will get for $k \in \{0,1,2,3\}$:
$$k=0 \rightarrow \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&2&1\end{array}\right], k=1 \rightarrow \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&-1&1\end{array}\right]$$
$$k=2 \rightarrow \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&1\end{array}\right], k=3 \rightarrow \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&1&1\end{array}\right]$$
These four are all integer combinations for the middle pixel but the end pixels stay 1 and has no imaginary part at all. This one I came up with by trial and error.

---

So to my question:

How to systematically make filter factorizations which achieve this? I.e. that some points stay the same (the end points in this case are both 1 irregardless of $k$), but other points cycle through different values?